# Is there a way to manually set the dy value in Animate.event?

Tags: react-native, react-animations

I want to be able to bring a table up to a certain height when a condition is matched. How do I manually set the value of dy? `this.state.drag.y` returns an object. If it were a simple value, I could manually set it, but how do I set dy manually in this scenario?

```
 onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
      return Animated.event([null, {
        dy: this.state.drag.y,
      }])(e, gestureState)
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out-

```
   return Animated.event([null, {
         dy: this.state.drag.setValue({ x: 0, y: "value" }),
       }])(e, gestureState)
```

where **value** can be anything you want to set manually.